# Toggle comments in Chrome devtools on non-english keyboard

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In Google Chrome's devtools you can toggle comments with the shortcut:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

On a keyboard with a Swedish layout this doesn't work as the <kbd>/</kbd> on an English keyboard is replaced with <kbd>-</kbd>, causing the text to zoom out instead.

Other combinations based on the position of <kbd>/</kbd> on the Swedish keyboard doesn't work either.

How to make it possible to toggle comments on non-english keyboard layouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug with some shortcuts that require to press a modifier key on non-english keyboard. Follow [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=462958) for the resolution.

**Edit** : I looked at the swedish keyboard layout. While the bug is still present, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>*</kbd>, this will send the code awaited for toggling comments (keycode 191)

Comment: Spot on! Thanks for the tip and the link.